# Retorno 404 de página apenas com dispositivos iOS

Tags: amazon-aws, nginx

Publiquei um aplicativo em www.yoohood.fun, criado com o create-react-app, usando um servidor AWS, e quando o usuário acessa com a conta do Facebook, é redirecionado para a pasta /sync. Porém, quando alguém acessa pelo iphone, seja pelo Safari, ou pelo Chrome, ou pelo safari em outros devices o retorno é um 404. Alguém pode me dar uma luz sobre qual problema pode estar acontecendo?

[image: 404 page]

O nginx tá assim:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name 54.233.226.167 yoohood.fun www.yoohood.fun;

    location / {
           proxy_pass http://172.31.0.12:5000;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }

}

server {

    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/https/ssl_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/https/server.key;

    server_name 54.233.226.167 yoohood.fun www.yoohood.fun;

    location / {
           proxy_pass http://172.31.0.12:5000;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }

}
```

Comment: Qual é a configuração do NginX?

Comment: Oi @Sergio, coloquei a configuração do nginx no corpo da pergunta. Consegue me dar uma idéia?